# Defining CustomMessageBox from Windows Phone Toolkit in XAML

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

Can I define CustomMessageBox in XAML? I have the code:

```
<phone:phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <toolkit:CustomMessageBox x:Key="CustomMessageBox" Title="Blabla" IsLeftButtonEnabled="True" LeftButtonContent="OK" Content="blabla" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And when I'm trying to run it:

```
(this.Resources["CustomMessageBox"] as CustomMessageBox).Show();
```

I get InvalidOperationException - "Element is already the child of another element.".

Is it possible to do it this way or I have to define it from code-behind? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I would recommend you to define in the code behind

Answer (score 0):

Due to [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/windows-phone-toolkit-in-depth-3rd-edition) book (not advertizing, just showing source), you can do follow:

1 Create new UserControl, name it CustomUserControl.xaml

2 Add custom UI elements to UC

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,10">
 <TextBlock Text="Custom content inside the UserControl XAML" TextWrapping="Wrap"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
 <MediaElement Source="http://mschannel9.vo.msecnd.net/o9/mix/09/wmv/key01.wmv"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

3 Run from codebehind of your main page

```
var messageBox = new CustomMessageBox
{
Content = new CustomUserControl(),
LeftButtonContent = "OK",
RightButtonContent = "Cancel",
};
messageBox.Show();
```

Seems now you can play video in message box :)

PS: also found some info [here](http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/)